# SharePoint restrict column edit

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, file

I am creating a document management system on O365 SharePoint Online. I have added several columns of data for each pdf which is uploaded to a folder.

I would like to temporarily "lock" a certain file in order to prevent changes to any of the columns. However, I and anyone with editing access needs to be able to "unlock" it as well to allow for changes.

Basically, I am trying to add a level of protection to the documents and make sure that the person changing the columns is meaning to do so. I know about the check in/out system, but I want anyone to be able to lock and unlock any document at any time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, the Check Out function means that the document is locked by xxx. Only xxx Check In(unlock) the document, other users can edit the document.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In my opinion, the Check Out/Check In can well support your needs. You can also Check Out (lock) document through powershell command. It's worth noting that this command can only be run as a site administrator.

```
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/"
$FileRelativeURL ="/sites/sitename/libraryname/Test.docx"
 
#Connect to PNP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Checkout the File
Set-PnPFileCheckedOut -Url $FileRelativeURL

#Checkin the File
#Set-PnPFileCheckedIn -Url $FileRelativeURL
```

Comment: Thanks @EchoDu_MSFT. The only problem with locking a document is that I need another member of my team to be able to unlock that same document to edit the properties if needed (and not wait until I unlock it). It is my understanding that this isn't possible.

Comment: Yes, Rachel. According to my research, only the corresponding user can check in the document that was checked out.